What's the difference between wordpress single tier and multi tier?
What's the difference between wordpress single tier and multi tier??
Can the instance of wordpress multi tier be escalated or de-escalated as single tier wordpress??
OR
Is there a provision for auto escalation or de-escalation ?? in wordpress multi tier.
I am quasi technical.
TIA
